# Writing XML according to a DTD

Tags: java, xml, dtd

I would like to know if there is a way (particularly, an **API**), in Java, to write a XML in a SAX-like way (i.e., event-like way, differently from JDOM, which I cannot use) that takes a DTD and guarantees that my XML document is being correctly written.

I have been using SAX for parsing and I have written a *XML writer layer* by myself as if I were writing a plain file (through `OutputStreamWriter`), but I have seen that my *XML writer layer* is not always following the DTD rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAX does not know to write XML documents. It is attended to parse them. So, you can choose any method you want to create document and then validate it using SAX API against DTD.

BTW may I ask you why are you limiting yourself to using tools that were almost obsolete about 10 years ago? Why not to use higher level API that converts objects to XML and vice versa? For example JAXB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You've made things clearer.

I'm using SAX because our software should read XML and keep a small memory footprint. Since I'm not used to XML manipulation, my development team suggested JDOM ("big" memory footprint for our purposes) and SAX, which I stuck to.

I'll read something about JAXB and other newer APIs as you've suggested. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

The Standard DocumentBuilder methodology can validate for you.

This snippet taken from http://www.edankert.com/validate.html#Validate_using_internal_DTD

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = 
    SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(
    new Source[] {new StreamSource("contacts.xsd")}));

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

builder.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());

Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource("document.xml"));
```